# Is there a difference to importing specific functions/variables vs importing it entirely?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

When importing functions in for example, ReactJS, I normally import only specific functions.

```js
import { useEffect, useState, /* ETC... */ } from 'react';
```

But is there a difference to just importing the whole module?

```js
import React from 'react';
```

Except for the fact that you'll need to do `React.useState()` instead of `useState()`, is there a difference in performance? Does it load faster etc. I know it probably reads the entire file in both cases but is anything else affected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very good question. I have already installed the extension `Import Cost` from VSCode which let you know the import size cost of each library and the way you import that.

This library has a post explaining it in detail. [Medium Import Cost Post](https://citw.medium.com/keep-your-bundle-size-under-control-with-import-cost-vscode-extension-5d476b3c5a76)

I try to test it and the result is different depending on the way you import everything or just the method.
[image: Default import]

VS

[image: Selective importing]

Comment: Awesome, this is the type of answer i was looking for, straightforward and detailed. Thanks!